# how can i get customer already bought products list in magento2

Tags: magento2

The answer is [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/199903/59599)

I want to check **my current cart products** with **customer already bought products** for disallow repeated buyers for specified category.

I'm getting current cart products like this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// retrieve quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// retrieve quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();   //citem means Cart items :)

foreach($items as $item) {   
   echo $item->getProductId().'<br />';   // current product id


}
```

Help me to get customer already bought products list

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you mean order history ?

Comment: Yes mr @MGento i want to get order history by customer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using below code, you will get all previously purchased products of logged in customer.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");
$customerId = $customerSession->getCustomerId();
$orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter("customer_id", $customerId);

$products = array();
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $products[] = $item->getProductId();
    }
}
$product_list = array_unique($products);
print_r($product_list);
```

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh Yadav, But i can't see the results, i'm working on onepage.phtml from megento module-checkout

Comment: @ubakarasamy check if the current customer has a previous order or not?

Comment: https://screenshots.firefox.com/Va3rBYnNntD1vn19/localhost 
Yes @Dinesh Yadav current customer have previous orders

Comment: Can you post your updated code in your question?

Comment: @ubakarasamy If my answer helped you, you can accept the answer so it can help others also.